# Playback multiple videos with third video audio using AviSynth

Tags: video, avidemux, avisynth

I have three videos, only two have the same image dimensions. I can playback the videos synchronized using AviSynth:

```
clip1 = DirectShowSource("leftVideo.avi", audio=false)
clip2 = DirectShowSource("rightVideo", audio=false)

StackHorizontal(clip1,clip2)
```

Now, the third video actually has the audio I want to play, and has a different format and dimension from the first two. I can play one of the first two videos with the third video's audio like this:

```
Video=AVISource("leftVideo.avi")
Audio=AVISource("thirdVideo.avi")
AudioDub(Video,Audio)
```

My question is: How can I play all three videos at once, with the first two videos (leftVideo, rightVideo) stacked horizontally above, and have the third video show both video and audio centered below the horizontal stack?

Bonus: Is there a way to show the third video (audio and video) stacked constantly on the left, and manipulate the right video to toggle between the other two videos (via hotkey)?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you will want to mod your lines to be like this:

```
clip1 = DirectShowSource("leftVideo.avi", audio=false)
clip2 = DirectShowSource("rightVideo", audio=false)
return = StackHorizontal(clip1, clip2)
Audio = AVISource("thirdVideo.avi")

AudioDub(return, Audio)
```